# How do I handle transactions without code duplication?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, transactions, action-filter

I seem to repeat myself everytime that I want to use transaction in my POST methods. Can I use an action filter or something?

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual ActionResult Create(CreateModel model)
{
  if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    return View(model);

  var instruction = new Instruction(CurrentUser);
  Mapper.Map(model, instruction);

  // how do I get rid of this?
  using (var uow = _unitOfWorkFactory.Create())
  {
    _repository.Save(instruction);

    uow.SaveChanges();
  }

  return RedirectToAction("Details", new {id = instruction.Id});
}
```

Comment: Arguably you should not be writing to the database directly in your controllers.  Thus IMO, this is the wrong place/layer to perform this abstraction.  (For example, in my code I do it at the WCF layer)

Comment: I agree... Unless its a quick and dirty implementation - say a prototype

Comment: @KirkWoll: Using domain models and repositories in the controller is perfectly valid in DDD. I don't use bastard objects as I describe here: http://blog.gauffin.org/2012/06/protect-your-data/

Comment: Nothing wrong with domain models, but you're baking in transactional database behavior into your controllers.  IMO, that's not the role of the web server.

Comment: No. I'm adding transactional behavior to an action (which happens to exist in a webserver). The kind of transaction depends on the UoW implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new action filter which checks the `ModelState` and the `HttpContext.Error` property before creating and using an UnitOfWork:

```
public class TransactionalAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
  private IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

  public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
  {
    if (filterContext.Controller.ViewData.ModelState.IsValid && filterContext.HttpContext.Error == null)
      _unitOfWork = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IUnitOfWork>();

    base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
  }

  public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
  {
    if (filterContext.Controller.ViewData.ModelState.IsValid && filterContext.HttpContext.Error == null && _unitOfWork != null)
      _unitOfWork.SaveChanges();

    base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
  }
}
```

A sample nhibernate implementation of the UnitOfWork (register it in your IoC):

```
public class NhibernateUnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
  private readonly ISession _session;
  private ITransaction _transaction;

  public NhibernateUnitOfWork(ISession session)
  {
    _session = session;
    _transaction = session.BeginTransaction();
  }

  public void Dispose()
  {
    if (_transaction == null)
      return;

    if (!_transaction.WasCommitted)
      _transaction.Rollback();

    _transaction.Dispose();
    _transaction = null;
  }

  public void SaveChanges()
  {
    _transaction.Commit();
  }

}
```

Usage:

```
[HttpPost, Transactional]
public virtual ActionResult Create(CreateModel model)
{
  if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    return View(model);

  var instruction = new Instruction(CurrentUser);
  Mapper.Map(model, instruction);
  _repository.Save(instruction);

  return RedirectToAction("Details", new {id = instruction.Id});
}
```

Source: http://blog.gauffin.org/2012/06/how-to-handle-transactions-in-asp-net-mvc3/